# Browse through a pop-up?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, watin

I want to test the links that appear in a pop up in a website after pressing a button. The problem is that I dont know how to do it. I dont know the name of any buttons of the popup, and even dont know if the watin can navegate through it.

I used to check links in a website searching the button by the name (using development tool from IE to search the name of the buttons), but with the pop up I dont know.

How can i do it? There is a function to work with pop ups? How can I get the name of the elements of the pop up?

Answer (score 0):

All website pages are html, javascript and css - all human readable.

Try viewing the source.

ps They are readable unless they are Flash type applications.

Comment: and if i find the name of the elements of the popup, watin will work with it? the browser will have the url of the website, not of the pop up. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Install the Web Developer extension for Firefox, right-click on the element, choose Inspect Element.

Comment: will watin works with pop ups with a Button.Find("")? Or i have to use another function?

Answer (score 0):

You have to attach to that popup. Treat it like a normal IE window. I don't remember correctly, but try something like that:

```
var popup = IE.AttachTo<IE>(Find.ByTitle("Title of the popup"));
```